# sharedPreference from helper class

Tags: android, static, sharedpreferences

I have an application where i store info data in a sharedPreference
I want to create a static class which will hold the data from the sharedPreference (get and set) so i will not have to call each time to the sharedPreference(performance issues)
The static helper class dont have reference to the sharedPreference, is there any way to get hold of it without passing the calling activity as parameter?
Maybe getParent() ? or getContext() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have 2 ways to do it :

- You can pass a `Context` in the parameters of all your static methods. Then just use `context.getSharedPreferences()`.
- Create a static `init` method where you record the data of your `SharedPreferences` in static fields of your class.

For my perspective I prefer n°1 because in n°2 you have to call `init`and modify it each time you add a new data in the `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing a Singleton class for this purpose. I am not sure if sharedpreference has a performance issue.

With a singleton class, you could store objects compared to shared preferences (strings).

Comment: I saw no issues with direct access to shared preferences by getters/setters too.

Comment: SharedPreferences is actually a Singleton Class, when you call getSharedPreferences you are actually getting a single instance and there are no penalty in performance for number of calls you get sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to write your own `MyApplication extends Application`, where you can store whatever you want in scope of entire application and define whatever "static" methods you want. You could access to it via `(MyApplication)yourActivityInstance.getApplication()`.

Answer (score 0):

You will somehow have to pass a `Context` to your static class, preferably an application context. I suggest you override the `onCreate()` method of the `Application` class (you would need to subclass it) and set the context reference in your static class to `getApplicationContext()` from there. This way you can access the shared preference accessors from any other application component (`Activity`, `Service`, ...) without supplying the `Context` every time.

Comment: You would never want to keep a static reference to an Activity. That would be a great way to create a horrible memory leak. You could instead create a static reference to an ApplicationContext using context.getApplicationContext();

Comment: ...which is what I was saying.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but here is an easy way i created.

Instead of creating your own SharedPreferences Helper class every time for every project you can **use this open source library** i created and make life simpler.

[Android-SharedPreferences-Helper](http://Android-SharedPreferences-Helper)

**Add this dependency and get started:**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    compile(group: 'com.viralypatel.sharedpreferenceshelper', name: 'library', version: '1.1.0', ext: 'aar')
}
```

**Usage**

**Check the repository page for details about using advanced features.**